# Onclick using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been trying to implement a JS call from a seperate script and despite referencing m,ultiple demo I cannot get my example to work.

Can someone help me trouble shoot this simple example?

tescript.php says

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!-- Load checkout JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="tscript.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 imageUploadSide">
    <ul>
    <li> <button id="buyingPhoto" class="btn btn-buy">A New Buyit Button</button>   
   </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Then the script file says

```
// checking script load & log
console.log("script file has been loaded")

$('#buyingPhoto').on('click', function() {
console.log("Can a button be depressed?")
});
```

I get a console log that the script has loaded (troubleshooting step 1) but the onclick itself doesn't run

Comment: Did you verify that the JavaScript file's name was named the same as the name you specified in your HTML code?

Comment: Try placing the script before `</body>` at the end of your page or at least after your HTML.

Comment: Did you import jquery library ?

Comment: The tscript.js reference is proved as I receive the "script file has been loaded" console log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing to import jQuery library .`$()` is jQuery using. And be careful about order of libraries. And be sure also page is loaded. So you should use `document.ready`.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tscript.js"></script>
```

```js
console.log("script file has been loaded")

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#buyingPhoto').on('click', function() {
       console.log("Can a button be depressed?")
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 imageUploadSide">
    <ul>
    <li> <button id="buyingPhoto" class="btn btn-buy">A New Buyit Button</button>   
   </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

without jquery

```js
document.getElementById("buyingPhoto").onclick = function() {
console.log("Can a button be depressed?")

};
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 imageUploadSide">
    <ul>
    <li> <button id="buyingPhoto" class="btn btn-buy">A New Buyit Button</button>   
   </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

or you can give click in html

```js
function test(){

console.log("Can a button be depressed?")

}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 imageUploadSide">
    <ul>
    <li> <button onclick="test()" id="buyingPhoto" class="btn btn-buy">A New Buyit Button</button>   
   </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you., I have added the jquery as you have demonstrated (i knew it'd be something simple)
However it still does not work on my server.
Is there something else I should check?

Comment: Did you put it above of another script tag? Order of script tag is important

Comment: This is the entire .php file

'code' <!-- Load checkout JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="tscript.js"></script>
<!-- Load JQuery Library -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 imageUploadSide">
    <ul>
    <li> <button id="buyingPhoto" class="btn btn-buy">A New Buyit Button</button>   
   </li>
   </ul>
 </div>'

Comment: ok put jquey script above the another script. Check my answer again and look at their orders

Comment: thanks for helping. I have changed the order to your response (in fact i copied it exactly) for both files and it doesnt work. 

I only have a cookie warning in the console

Comment: can u create jsfiddle then put your html tag there and give link then i  can understand problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214044/discussion-between-brad-and-pc-coder).

Answer (score 1):

Your whole code is correct. You have not included jquery library, just include the below CDN in your `<head></head>`section.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```